# django objects.filter(x__in = y) where y is repetitive QuerySet

Tags: django, filter, unique, one-to-many

```
Customer.objects.filter(customer_id__in=contact_list_senders)
```

contact_list_senders is a repetitive QuerySet that involves some customer_ids:

> {sender_id1, sender_id2, sender_id1, sender_id2, sender_id1}

When I try to find the Customer objects from the contact_list_senders QuerySet with the above code

Actual Output:

> {Customer1, Customer2}

Desired Output

> {Customer1, Customer2, Customer1, Customer2, Customer1}

I understand the actual output makes sense because there are only 2 Customer objects that matches with these contacts. Can you please help me to get the desired outcome?

models.py:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=False, null=False)
    enrollment_method = models.CharField(max_length=244, blank=True, null=False)
    account_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0000.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    reserved_balance = models.DecimalField(default=0000.00, max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Is it possible you want to have the final result in a form of a dictionary: {sender_id1: Customer1, sender_id2: Customer2} etc. ? It would make more sense.

Comment: As long as I can combine the contact_list and customer_list to pass them on to UI any way is acceptable. I used zip(contact_list, customer_list) to do that but dictionary is also fine.. not sure how that solves the problem with customer_list having only unique values though.